# Laravel policy show THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un problema, me da el error 403 THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED.

en mi UserController tengo esto

```
  public function show($id)
    {
      
        $user =  User::findOrFail($id);
        $this->authorize($user);
        return view('pages.perfil',compact('user'));
    }
```

En el UserPolicy tengo esto

```
  
    public function show(User $authUser,User $user)
    {  
         return $authUser->id === $user->id;
    }
```

y en mi AuthServiceProvider

```
 protected $policies = [
        User::class => UserPolicy::class,
    ];
```

Comment: Es algo confusa tu policy ¿por qué 2 veces el mismo modelo con 2 objetos distintos?, ¿nos explicas mejor lo que tratas de resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ya pude encontrar la solución, el metodo en UserPolicy se debe llamar view no show, si hay alguna mejor manera igual pueden dejarlo comentado, un saludo!